# How can i capture all Database table/view activity for the login id?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can i capture all Database table/view activity for the avtex login
id in server for a week long period (July 3 - 12)?  Specifically I
would like to get a list of tables/views accessed using this login.

Below are the avtex login id's  'avtex'@'172.16.%'  'avtex'@'192.168.%

How can i get particular user activitys ffrom show profiles?

Comment: so, thats the login id, whats the database called, etc. etc.

Comment: @jodrell databases names like partner,demand-new,mmt,dribsc..etc

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SHOW PROFILES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-profiles.html) for the current session but, unless you've implemented an audit trail to record user activity then historic activity is not stored.

It would be expensive for a database server to record all activity for all databases on the off chance.

Comment: is it possible to capture using script?

Comment: @user2545955 I don't know, sorry.